# Load remote Lisp files

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, tramp

Maybe it's an unusual case, but I like to connect to a remote computer running Clozure CL AND compiling there some files, which are located on my local desktop.

So, what I've achieved by now is to connect to my remote Lisp box. I've done it using Emacs. Therefore I've added some lines to my .emacs file:

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))

(require 'slime)
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
```

It seems to be working fine. After setup my ssh tunnel with

`ssh -L4005:127.0.0.1:4005 pi@192.168.0.100`

I get the normal REPL from Clozure CL within my local emacs.

Also, if I want to load a file from any PC in my network via ssh in Emacs I can do it. But if I try to compile the buffer with the recently (in Emacs) loaded file I get always this error:

```
File "/ssh:ingmar@192.168.0.103:/home/ingmar/Dokumente/Lisp/util.lisp" does not exist.
   [Condition of type CCL::SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY-LOAD] Retry loading "/ssh:ingmar@192.168.0.103:/home/ingmar/Dokumente/Lisp/util.lisp"
 1: [SKIP-LOAD] Skip loading "/ssh:ingmar@192.168.0.103:/home/ingmar/Dokumente/Lisp/util.lisp"
 2: [LOAD-OTHER] Load other file instead of "/ssh:ingmar@192.168.0.103:/home/ingmar/Dokumente/Lisp/util.lisp"
 3: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 5: [ABORT-BREAK] Reset this thread
 --more--

Backtrace:
  0: (NIL #<Unknown Arguments>)
  1: (CCL::%LOAD "/ssh:ingmar@192.168.0.103:/home/ingmar/Dokumente/Lisp/util.lisp" NIL NIL :ERROR :DEFAULT NIL)
  2: (NIL #<Unknown Arguments>)
```

How can I tell the remote Lisp box where to find the files? I have also tried to insert a load statement into the REPL like `load ssh://...`, but with the same result.

Does anybody have some suggestions what to do, so that I can compile local files on a remote Lisp box? I would assume that's not really a new thing, as Lisp can be operated remotely for quite a while...

Comment: You could add lisp code to download your files first, either directly in lisp or with a system command (using ssh together with tar to get a directory of your lisp files). If these lisp files don't take too much space this could be an easy workaround.

Answer (score 3):

For your particular case, I suggest you compile the buffer (select the whole buffer <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>, then <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>), not the file (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd>).

The annoyance is that this changes the buffer's point and mark. Hopefully, you won't be compiling a whole buffer all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The `tramp` package and file names of the form `/ssh:user@host:path...` are Emacs features, which is why they don't work in Clozure.

Unless Clozure itself supports loading code over ssh, which is fairly unlikely, you will need to rethink your strategy. One option would be to edit the files locally and use `rsync` to easily synchronize the changes over your ssh ssh tunnel, so that the latest files are visible to Clozure.

Comment: OK, thanks. Seem to me inconvenient in the light of modern completely integrated IDEs, which we have today. But it should work and I will try to setup rsync in conjunction with ssh.

Comment: You can also just use Dropbox; makes things a bit more automated.

Comment: @metaman, what other IDE allows you to edit a file in a remote machine and load things from it into an application running in another remote machine? (This is a honest question.)